# Spring MVC REST service - maven embedded Jetty gives 404

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jetty

I created a Spring MVC web app which only offers a restful service (and a default welcome page for manually testing if it gets deployed correctly).

I also have some integration tests testing my REST services using Rest Assured. Problem of course is that these test are run when building, but at this moment the webapp is not yet online so these tests will always fail. This is meant to be solved using an embedded Jetty server. So I put the following in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>WebApp</finalName>
    </plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/WebApp</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                        <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run the command `mvn jetty:run` the jetty server starts and I can see my welcome page when I point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/WebApp`, but when I try to access any of my REST calls, I get a plain 404.

The REST services do work when deployed onto a tomcat or glassfish server.

I'm using a Java based Spring MVC configuration with only a dispatcher for REST since there are no 'real' web pages.

Can anyone give some insight into what I could be doing wrong here? Only when deploying to the embedded Jetty the REST service gives 404's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your service defined? What does the test do? Where is the code?

Comment: My service is defined in a WebApplicationInitializer class (no xml configs are used), but I'd doubt the error is there because the website runs on a Tomcat server. The test just performs a rest call and checks if the code is 200 OK and checks values in the responsebody. What code would you like me to add?

Answer (score -1):

Good news! I was able to solve this by changing

```
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.1.26</version>
```

to

```
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
```

So a newer version of the plugin did the trick (probably has to do with Java based configuration support). Hope this helps anyone else!